# How to install perl module and include in Perl script?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am new to the Perl. I've downloaded `HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14.tar.gz` I want to know how to install it.

I am using Windows.

How to include this in my perl script?

I've opened `cpan` using run command and installed HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14 using the command `install HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14`, but I got the following error:

```
Writing C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata
Warning: Cannot install HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the *module name*, not the distribution name:

```
install HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath
```

You don't need to download the distribution first, `cpan` will do that for you.

Comment: Then after installation has finished how to include this tree builder in my script.

Comment: Try the [manual for the module](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm#SYNOPSIS)

Comment: Got error if i do like following use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

Comment: Can't locate HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Dwimperl/perl/
site/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .) at Multi_instance_r
un1.pl line 7.

Comment: Either something is really screwy with your INC path, or the module failed to install. Look for error messages from the installation attempt.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45364/discussion-between-vijay-and-quentin)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your valuable ideas..
I didn't get any error. I think so.
I am able to use HTML::TreeBuilder; but i cannot use use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath; What will be the error file name ? I am sure I didn't get anything like that .. How to find this.

Comment: HTML::TreeBuilder and HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath come in different distributions (the latter is an optional add-on to the former). Rerun the install command and look at what the console says.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that i found to install any perl module is :

Step 1 : open your os terminal

Step 2 : change path to bin folder path.
example(windows) -> cd C:\Strawberry\perl\bin

Step 3 : now run a command : perl cpan

Step 4 : type below command to check installation is working or not.
example(windows) ->       install App::cpanminus

Step 5 : now for installing any perl module do like this(for Convert::EBCDIC module) :
example(windows) -> install Convert::EBCDIC

Awesome, you are done!!

Answer (score -2):

Its easiest if you just run the CPAN shell from your machine ( type "cpan" ) and then just type "install HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14" from that shell.

It will go off and find the module and take care of the installation.

To then use it in your script just add:

use HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14;

before you make use of it

Comment: I am getting the following error.. Warning: Cannot install HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14, don't know what it is.     Try the command                                                                                                                                                     i /HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/                                                                                                                             to find objects with matching identifiers.

Comment: And the following error too. New CPAN.pm version (v2.00) available.                                          [Currently running version is v1.9800].You might want to try.install CPAN                                                                    reload cpan                                                                   to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving                 the current session.

Comment: What method are you using to install it ? from source or via CPAN's shell ? Also what platform are you on ? ( Linux / Windows )

Comment: I've downloaded HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14. This is in tar file format. Do I need to copy this file in any specific path.? Do I need to unzip ?